# Distinct for only one column when using left join

Tags: plsql, group-by, duplicates, distinct

So  I have this query:

```
select 
    distinct(netz.ID_CHILD), 
    netz.ID_PARENT, 
    teilstrecke.ID, 
    teilstrecke.XA, 
    teilstrecke.XE, 
    teilstrecke.YA, 
    teilstrecke.YE 
from netz
LEFT join teilstrecke 
    on teilstrecke.ID = netz.ID_CHILD
where id is not null
connect by prior ID_CHILD = ID_PARENT
    start with ID_PARENT = 'A1' 
order by id_child;
```

The problem is that I get id_child duplicated.

```
ID_CHILD   ID_PARENT  ID                 XA         XE         YA         YE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
B1         A1-1       B1                900        700        400        480 
B2         A1-2-2     B2                700        375        480        625 
G1         A1-1       G1                900        900        400        150 
G2         A1-1       G2                900        525        150        200 
G3         A1-2-1     G3                525        500        200        300 
G3         A1-1       G3                525        500        200        300 
G4         A1-2-2     G4                500        700        300        480  
G4         A1-1       G4                500        700        300        480 
G5         A1-2-1     G5                525        250        200        100 
G6         A1-2-1     G6                250        200        100        350 
G7         A1-2-2     G7                200        375        350        625 
G8         A1-2-2     G8                200        500        350        300 
G8         A1-2-1     G8                200        500        350        300
```

I tried it with the ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTICIPATION but the only thing i get returned is 1 and 2. no names. Working with group by didn't help as id_child was no group by expression.

Comment: G8 should G3 and G4 should only appear once. Because it's like a street map. And I need one way like G8 only once.

Comment: Remove `ID_PARENT` from the SELECT. And `distinct` is not a function. It applies to all columns in the SELECT clause. And are you sure, you use MySQL?

Comment: Removing ID_Parent does not affect the result. Yeah I removed the ( ). Yeah but how can I make it only for one column?

Comment: This is invalid MySQL code. MySQL doesn't support `connect by` looks like you are using Oracle database.

Comment: As @RaymondNijland mentions, this isn't MySQL, please correct your tags for the question.

Comment: Hello Lebron11   Do you have those values in the teilstrecke Table           
    A1-2-2     G8                200        500        350        300 
    A1-2-1     G8                200        500        350        300 or you get it by joinning the two table. what do you want to achieve with the connect by prior

Comment: @Lebron11 your data shows different values of ID_PARENT for the rows containing the duplicated ID_CHILD values.  Which parent value do you want to see in the results?  You should be able to achieve what you want by adding a ROW_NUMBER column with PARTITION BY ID_CHILD and ORDER BY whatever will sort the partitions so that the row you want comes first in each partition; then you can wrap the query in another SELECT ... WHERE your row_number column alias = 1.